# gmaps4rails not displaying map

Tags: google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I have the gmaps4rails gem installed and I'm not sure what's going on here, but I can't even get the demo code to work. Nothing at all is being loaded.

I have a rails 4.0.2 ruby 1.9.3 app.

I've followed the tutorial for the basic demo on the github page listed below: 
https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

I don't know if it's a JS issue - I also have:
highcharts and royal slider in there that may interfere.

I already tried the "data-no-turbolink" that's recommended here:https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/issues/357

There are no errors in the console when I run it. Below is the code. I have no idea why this isn't working, it's just the demo code and I didn't try to do anything tricky yet. Does anyone have any idea or has this happened to anyone?

show

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <div style='width: 800px;'>
        <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
    </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
            handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
                markers = handler.addMarkers([
                    {
                        "lat": 0,
                        "lng": 0,
                         "picture": {
                                "url": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png",
                                "width":  36,
                                "height": 36
                              },
                              "infowindow": "hello!"
                            }
                          ]);
                          handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
                          handler.fitMapToBounds();
                        });
                    </script>
```

application.js

```
//= require underscore
//= requrie gmaps/google
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a JS issue. Have you tried to insert the Google scripts to all your pages by adding them to your `application.html.erb`, rather than on your `show` page? There was a similar [issue](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/issues/390) on Github.

Basically, try to include the following inside the `<head>` in your `application.html.erb`, instead of your `show` page.

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.14&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.1.2/src/markerclusterer_packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, have you tried to restart the server after installing the gem?

Comment: sorry should have mentioned...I tried all of that before posting the question. It's really strange.

Answer (score 0):

Please check, 'underscore.js" is correct format.
In the demo, this js file copied by clipboard method. 
Please download 'underscore.zip' from github, extract, use right js file.
I was same situation, I solved with this checking

Comment: I am using the underscore-rails gem so I shouldn't have a problem with that, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
//= require underscore
//= requrie gmaps/google
```

Maybe it's just a typo?
Old question though

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was interference from another javascript library.

The morris.js library was throwing an error because it was looking for a graph container div and couldn't find one (one problem I have with not being able to use page specific javascript very easily).

This blocked other javascript, including gmaps, from loading.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you forgot to put

```html
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=[your API key]"></script>
```

for API it needed to generate